# Caching docker install requirements when using setup.cfg

Tags: python, docker

I'm currently trying to install a Python package as part of a Docker build. This Python package uses setup.cfg to store the metadata for its dependencies. With requirements.txt I'm able to cache the installation of the dependencies using something like:

```
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But this code is a pip-installable Python package that stores the dependency information in setup.cfg with a directory structure like this:

```
tree -L 2 .
.
├── mypy.ini
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── lib
├── tox.ini
```

Which is then installed like this:

```
COPY common /deps/common
RUN pip install file:///deps/common
```

Unfortunately this no longer caches the install of the requirements so any code change has to now go fetch and reinstall the python package dependencies each time. How do I cache the dependency installation specified by setup.cfg in a way that docker understands?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete Dockerfile?  Layer caching should still happen so long as the `common` file(s) are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

For **new versions of Docker** (e.g. Docker 23) with [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/) included you can specify a local caching command to `pip` in your Dockerfile like this:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

After you build your docker container the first time, the files downloaded by pip will be cached in your local file system, and subsequent docker builds will go faster due to less downloading.

Additionally, your docker containers will be **smaller** because pip's downloaded files will not be included in the docker image.